# Update two models with one view not working in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

Can anybody help me resolve my issue? I'm able to do create new records but I can't modify or update my existing records.

Here is my source code:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Branchmaster;
    $user = new Usermaster;
    if(isset($_POST['Branchmaster'], $_POST['Usermaster'])) {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Branchmaster'];
      $user->attributes=$_POST['Usermaster'];
      $valid=$model->validate();
      $valid=$user->validate() && $valid;
      if($valid){
         $model->save();
         $chnuser->save();                   
         $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->Id));
      }
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'user'=>$user,
    ));
  }

  public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $user = Usermaster::model()->findByAttributes(array('branch_id'=>$model->Id));
    if(isset($_POST['Branchmaster'], $_POST['Usermaster'])) {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Branchmaster'];
      $user->attributes=$_POST['Usermaster'];

      $valid=$model->validate();
      $valid=$user->validate() && $valid;
      if($valid){
        $model->save();
        $user->save();
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->Id));
      }
    }
    $this->render('update',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'user'=>$user,
    ));
  }
```

I need help for this problem... Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to check errors using $model->getErrors() and $user->getErrors()

Comment: its display msg - 'Array'

Comment: you need to dump it using CVarDumper::dump( $model->getErrors(),10,true);

Comment: @Letmesee hey thanks a lot for your help... now i done it :)...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of find 'findByAttr' so that will be

// pls note tht $id must be a primary key of this particular model

```
$user = Usermaster::model()->findByPk($id);
```

// If the situation don't allow a primary key then we can go for query execution

```
$update = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->update('usermaster', array('field1'=>'value','field2'=>'value2'),
'branch_id=:id',array(':id'=>$branch_id));
```

Comment: Is the problem with validation

Comment: hey thanks dude for your code... but i have done it.. i'm having error some data-types related..

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if id is exited than u have to do update...

use findByPk to load model...

than do process to same is above
here is sample code. you have to implement like these

```
         $model->attributes=$_POST['Branchmaster'];
         $user_post = $_POST['Usermaster'];
         $id = $user_post['id'];
         $user =  ModelName::model()->findByPk($id); 
         $user->variable_name = $variable_value


         $valid=$model->validate();
         $valid=$user->validate() && $valid;
         if($valid){
             $model->save();
             $user->save();
             $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->Id));
         }
```

Thanks

Comment: hey thanks dude for your code... but i have done it.. i'm having error some data-types related..

Comment: Can You enplane properly.which type of error is occur...??

Comment: Actually i having field Status and it's int type but may be default store as string..